# Running simple CECopy in CMD using Java

Tags: java, windows, batch-file, cmd, copy

I am trying to run a simple "cecopy" in java. I call "cmd.exe" and pass the command through. It creates the directories but doesnt carry out the copy.

Below is the command I am using, set as a string in java:

```
  String cmd = "mkdir \"C:\\\\Dominos\\\\DATFiles\" >> log.txt\n" 
  + "\n" + 
  "cecopy \"dev:\\Application\\\\MCL\\\\Projects\\\\Default\\\\aa.dat\" \"C:\\\\Dominos\\\\DATFiles\");
```

Below is how I am calling command prompt to execute the DOS statement:

```
 Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();                                                  
            try {                                                              
                Process p = rt.exec("cmd.exe /c" + cmd);     // Call CMD
                p.waitFor();                                 // Wait till CMD finishes
            } catch (InterruptedException | IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(readData.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
```

Any help?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can use process builder. It handles commands with arguments neatly.

```
ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder();
p.command("cmd_to_run", "args_if_any");
p.start();
```

Comment: Thank you, will try this now, will let you know what happens

Comment: So I tried using a ProcessBuilder but it didn't solve the issue: 

I implemented the following code:

`ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder();  `
     `pb.command("cmd.exe", "/C" + cmd);  `
    `pb.start(); `

Comment: I Used the process builder to output a redirectError! I found my issue! Thanks!